# How to query from range?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([range] varchar(9), [sector] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([range], [sector])
VALUES
    ('684-733', 2),
    ('563-598', 3),
    ('514-544', 2),
    ('640-682', 3),
    ('1053-1152', 2)
;
```

I want to get information by passing a predicate
So far I have this

```
select sector from table1 where [range] = 564
```

expected outcome

> 3

Is there any function I can use to get the data?

Comment: As a DBA you should know better than to store multiple values in a column. To do this, you need to split the string (splitting functions you can find with a trivial search) into a table and join

Comment: Agreed, fix the design. You're storing delimited data *and* storing numerical values as a `varchar`; so your value '564', for example, is **less than** the value `'42'`.

Comment: you're right, I think I will change the approach. 

just experimenting with statistics and histogram so the number of rows won't exceed 200 in my environment at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a number as a string like this could cause many issues later. Your best move is refactoring the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
([beginrange] int, [endrange] int, [sector] int)

Insert into table1 values
(684, 733, 2)
...
```

You would then get your result with:

```
select sector from table1 where 564 between [beginrange] and [endrange]
```

That said, if you do not have control over this table, you'll need to parse the string into two integers:

```
select * from table1 where 580 between convert(int, substring([range], 0, charindex('-', [range]))) and convert(int, substring([range], charindex('-', [range]) + 1, len([range])))
```

You can look up the various functions used [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks i will try

Comment: I took your advice and changed accordingly. I think it was foolish of me to store it as string.

Comment: If only I had a dollar for every bad development choice I've ever made...  : )

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [range] varchar(9), [sector] int);
INSERT INTO @tbl ([range], [sector]) VALUES
('684-733', 2),
('563-598', 3),
('514-544', 2),
('640-682', 3),
('1053-1152', 2);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @param INT = 564;

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , LEFT([range], pos -1) AS [start]
        , RIGHT([range], LEN([range]) - pos) AS [end]
    FROM @tbl
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('-', [range])) AS t(pos)
)
SELECT sector 
FROM rs
WHERE @param BETWEEN [start] AND [end];
```

**Output**

```
+--------+
| sector |
+--------+
|      3 |
+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks i will try

Comment: Pet peeve, but it's not `;WITH`, it's just `WITH`. `;` goes at the end of all your statements not the start of those that require the *prior* statement to be terminated. Yeah I've already terminated the prior so the semi colon makes less sense as well here.

Comment: @Lamu, old habits die hard.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL Server 2016 and later you can use `string_split` :

```
select sector
from table1 t1
cross apply string_split(t1.range, '-') y
group by sector 
having 564 between min(y.value) and max(y.value)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d799a8a4693b1d6c9fe4f536f093426b)*

Comment: Thanks i will try

Answer (score 1):

use a cross apply and a case statement to find a range where 564 is between the start and end values

```
 select
  tbl1.range,
 case when 564 between Lookup.startValue  and Lookup.endValue then
    tbl1.sector
 end Sector
 from @tbl tbl1
 cross apply
 (
 select 
 tbl2.range,
 tbl2.sector,
 cast(left(tbl2.range,charindex('-',tbl2.range)-1) as int) startValue,
 cast(right(tbl2.range,len(tbl2.range)-charindex('-',tbl2.range)) as int) endValue
 from @tbl tbl2
 where tbl1.range=tbl2.range
 )Lookup
 where
 case when 564 between Lookup.startValue  and Lookup.endValue then
   tbl1.sector
 end is not null
```

output:

```
  range Sector
  563-598   3
```